# Why do the error derivatives become small if we start with a large learning rate?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, gradient-descent

In these slides from Hinton ([https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~tijmen/csc321/slides/lecture_slides_lec6.pdf](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Etijmen/csc321/slides/lecture_slides_lec6.pdf)) there is this statement:
[image]

I don't understand why "The error derivatives for the hidden units will all become tiny" if we start with a big learning rate. And if so, would there be the vanishing gradient problem?
I found conflicting information on the internet...

Could you please explain what happens in this specific situation? Both from an intuitive and mathematical point of view

Answer (score 1):

So in the case of sigmoid neurons, having large weights means the hidden unit output saturates, so then changes in the weights have minimal effect on the hidden unit output, and therefore the error gradient too.

I can't see this exactly happening with RELU type nonlinearities. so I would question whether these notes were specific to sigmoids ( pre RELU?).  RELU: If you have large weights then you are far from the nonlinear region at zero, so you have your sigmoid output layer and lots of effectively linear hidden layers, so the saturation of the output layer has same effect as mentioned above for sigmoid hidden units